# python if user input contains string

Tags: python, string, if-statement, input, python-3.x

Very basic question.
We have the code:

```
a = input("how old are you")

if a == string:
    do this

if a == integer (a != string):  
    do that
```

Obviously it doesn't work that way. But what is the easiest way to do this.
Thanks for any answers in advance.

We could also say:

```
if string in a:
    do this
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. What do you want?

Comment: *"But what is the easiest way to do this"*.. Do what?

Comment: It's important to note that `input` is always going to return a string. What you seem to be looking for is a way to detect whether that string contains digits. Make sure you understand the distinction.

Comment: I'm sorry if didn't ask the question very well. Ashwini Chaudhary's answer was perfect. That's all I needed. I was just getting an error in my app everytime the user inputted a letter rather than a number so I wanted the input box to stay in a loop, which broke if the input was an integer. Sorry if the question was asked badly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `str.isdigit` and `str.isalpha`:

```
if a.isalpha():
   #do something
elif a.isdigit():
   #do something
```

help on `str.isdigit`:

```
>>> print str.isdigit.__doc__
S.isdigit() -> bool

Return True if all characters in S are digits
and there is at least one character in S, False otherwise.
```

help on `str.isalpha`:

```
>>> print str.isalpha.__doc__
S.isalpha() -> bool

Return True if all characters in S are alphabetic
and there is at least one character in S, False otherwise.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a.isalpha(), a.isdigit(), a.isalnum() to check if a is composed of letters, numbers, or a combination of numbers and letters, respectively.

```
if a.isalpha(): # a is made up of only letters
    do this

if a.isdigit(): # a is made up of only numbers
    do this

if a.isalnum(): # a is made up numbers and letters
    do this
```

The Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) will tell you in more detail the methods you can call on strings.

Comment: input will always be a string

Answer (score 0):

Seen that you use input() in tour example you should know that input always give you a string. And you need to cast it to the correct type, EG: Int, or Float.

```
def isint(input):
    return input.isdigit()

def isfloat(input):
    try: 
        return float(input) != None;
    except ValueError: 
        return False;

def isstr(input):
    if not isint(input) and not isfloat(input):
        return True
    return False

print isint("3.14")
print isfloat("3.14")
print isstr("3.14")
```