# Python If/else statements with math

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been trying to make a circle area calculator, and I've got the basics. But if the user enters something like `5m`, then I see an error. Instead of exiting with an error, I want to return "Enter a Number". Here is my code.

```
from math import pi

r = float(input("Input the radius of the circle : "))
print("The area of the circle with radius " + str(r) + " is: " + str(pi * r**2))

if r==(str):
    print("Enter a Number")
```

Comment: What are you trying to check with `if r==(str)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python if user input contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453626/python-if-user-input-contains-string)

Comment: @SruthiV:  That'd accomplish nothing, given that `r` is already cast to a `float` by the time they're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here

```
if r==(str):
```

doesn't do what you are expecting.

You want to use `string` module for this check (Note that this should be done before attempting to convert input to a float):

```
import string
if set(r).issubset(string.digits)
```

Or there is a method on string object for this check:

```
r.isdigit()
```

But there is a better way:

```
from math import pi
try:
    radius = float(input("Input the radius of the circle : "))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input, enter a Number!")
else:
    print("The area of the circle with radius " + str(r) + " is: " + str(pi * r**2))
```

This shows how to handle invalid inputs. You may want to put this in a loop until you get a valid input.

Comment: Im really new to python so the things you first mentioned didnt make much sense but the last one made sense thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can repeatedly ask until a string that can be converted to a float is entered. You can detect failure to convert the string to a float by catching `ValueError`, which is the exception thrown when a type conversion fails.

```
while True:
    try:
        r = float(input("Input the radius of the circle : "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Do this in place of your current line containing the `input` call, and get rid of the `r == (str)` test, which does not actually do anything close to what you are intending.

Also note if you are using Python2 you will need the `raw_input` function rather than `input`.