# what is wrong with this python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a function, which returns length, if string is passed and prints something, if an integer is passed. But, it is calculating the length of the integer also.

here is my code :

```
def string_length(mystring):
    if type(mystring) == int:
         return "Sorry, integers don't have length"
    else:
         return len(mystring)
str = input ( "enter a string" )
print ( string_length(str))
```

the output is

```
 "C:\Users\Naveen Reddy\PycharmProjects\Assignments\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Naveen Reddy/PycharmProjects/Assignments/passing int as argument, which should have strings.py"
enter a string222
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and the output for string is :

```
    "C:\Users\Naveen Reddy\PycharmProjects\Assignments\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Naveen Reddy/PycharmProjects/Assignments/passing int as argument, which should have strings.py"
enter a stringabcd
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `input` *always* returns a string. The string `'222'`  has length 3, which your program correctly reports.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17453678/6622587

Comment: python doesn't use `{}`. And why don't put at least a space after the input prompt?

Comment: okay, Thanks.
after having read code from that link, I'll use "isalpha" to check if input is a string, and if that turns out yes, returns length and if not, print something.

now my code looks like this (inside of flower brackets {def str_leng (aa):
    if aa.isalpha():
        return len(aa)
    else:
        return "integers doesn't has length"

abc = input("enter your string\n")
print(str_leng(abc)) }