# How to filter for integers within this program?

Tags: python

Essentially, what I want it to do, is to print whether the word does begin or not begin with a vowel. In addition to that, I want it to be able to print 'Entry must be a word' anytime something besides a string is put into the input. Right now if you put 56 into the input it comes up with 'Word does not begin with a vowel' which is not what I want. I need to narrow down my elif statement more so if someone could help me that would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

I've already tried various ways on trying to make this program filter for integers but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
word = input('Enter a word: ').lower()
if word[0] in 'aeiou':
  print('Word begins with a vowel')
elif word[0] not in 'aeiou':
  print('Word does not begin with a vowel')
else:
  print('Entry must be a word')
```

I need this program to filter for integers and other types by printing out the else statement's words, 'Entry must be a word'.

Comment: refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453626/python-if-user-input-contains-string)

Comment: @U10-Forward it is. The poster converts the input to lower case in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using this as the second condition:

```
elif word[0].isalpha():
```

If you wanted to use regex, which will help when you get to using more complex string patterns and conditions than you have here, it would be:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[a-z]')

elif pattern.match(word[0])
```

For more on regex, you can look here:

https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

EDIT: Correction, thanks to U10-Forward for pointing out my error.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why not? I've tested it just now, it seems to work perfectly. The input is already converted to lower case. If it wasn't, then '[A-Za-z]' would be the string expression needed.

Comment: Test with something that doesn't start with an `a` or a `z`